# If $y=(x^2-3x+5) (2x-7)$, find $\frac{dy}{dx}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

It is giving me problem in solving it. I've tried it like this : $$y'=u {dv\over dx}+v {du\over dx}=(x^2-3x+5)$$

Comment: It's a polynomial!  Just multiply it out and differentiate term by term if all else fails.

Answer (score 0):

The elementary way is to expand the brackets then take the derivative! In this case, the derivative of $(2x^3 - 7x^2) + (-6x^2 + 21x) + (10x - 35)$, or $2x^3 - 13x^2 + 31x - 35$ is $2(3x^2) - 13(2x) + 31$ using the power law, or $6x^2 - 26x + 31$.

But as you mentioned, there is another way to solve the expression using the product rule. Let u be $(x^2-3x+5)$, and v be $(2x-3)$. Then u' = $2x - 3$, and v' = $2$. Plugging these values into the product rule, which is $uv' + u'v$ gives:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=(x^2-3x+5)(2)+(2x-3)(2x-7)$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}= 2x^2-6x+10 + 4x^2 - 14x - 6x + 21 =6x^2-26x+31$$